# How to fix Maximum call stack size exceeded in minesweeper

Tags: javascript, html, css, minesweeper

I make a minesweeper today using pure js and css. When one block is clicked other blocks are opened using recursion. First I was using it for `10x10` board. It was working completely fine. But now when I made a `50x50` board. It gives error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Here is my complete code. Its much but you have to only concentrate on `openBlock` function which is called recursively. There are only 10 mines in `50x50` board. So all the blocks should open up except mines in almost all the cases. But some of the blocks are not opened due to the error.

```js
// -1 => mine
// 0 => a block without touching any mine
// 1 => block touching 1 mine
// etc

//Helper Methods
//Short for querySelector and querySelectorAll
const qs = str => document.querySelector(str);
const qsa = str => document.querySelectorAll(str);

//To create an element
const ce = ({ tag, style, ...rest }) => {
   const element = document.createElement(tag);
   if (rest) {
      for (let k in rest) {
         element[k] = rest[k];
      }
   }
   return element;
};

const main = qs("#main");
//Main variables
let len, wid, mines, blocks;
let isPlaying = true;

//Helping Data
let touchingBlockArr = [
   [1, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [1, 1],
   [1, -1]
];
touchingBlockArr = touchingBlockArr.concat(
   touchingBlockArr.map(x => x.map(a => -a))
);

//Object to assign colors for different numbers.
const colorObj = {
   "-1": "red",
   0: "gray",
   1: "blue",
   2: "orange",
   3: "green",
   4: "purple",
   5: "maroon"
};

//Function to create new game.
function newGame(l, w, m = 10) {
   len = l;
   wid = w;
   mines = m;
   main.innerHTML = "";
   game = [];
   blocks = [];
   createBoard();
}

//Create board
function createBoard() {
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      let tr = ce({ tag: "tr" });
      blocks.push([]);
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
         let td = ce({
            className: "block",
            tag: "td",
            onclick: onBlockClick,
            id: `${i},${j}`
         });
         tr.appendChild(td);
         td.id = `${i},${j}`;
         blocks[blocks.length - 1].push(td);
      }
      main.appendChild(tr);
   }
   addMines();
   setValues();
}

//Adding Mines
function addMines() {
   let addedMines = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < mines; i++) {
      let str, randX, randY;
      //To avoid repition of mines on same block.
      do {
         randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * wid);
         randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
         str = `${randX},${randY}`;
      } while (addedMines.includes(str));
      addedMines.push(str);

      blocks[randX][randY].classList.add("mine");
      blocks[randX][randY].setAttribute("data-value", -1);
   }
}

//Set Numbers for each block
function setValues() {
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
         let val;
         let tile = +blocks[i][j].dataset.value;
         if (tile !== -1) {
            val = touchingBlockArr.filter(([y, x]) => {
               if (blocks[i + y] && blocks[i + y][j + x]) {
                  return +blocks[i + y][j + x].dataset.value === -1;
               }
            }).length;
         }
         val = val === undefined ? -1 : val;
         blocks[i][j].setAttribute("data-value", val);
         blocks[i][j].style.color = colorObj[val];
      }
   }
}


function openSingleBlock(td) {
   let val = +td.dataset.value;
   if (val === -1) {
   } else {
      td.innerHTML = val || "";
   }
   td.classList.add("opened");
}


//When a left mouse button is clicked
function onBlockClick() {
   if (this.classList.contains("flagged")) return false;
   let val = +this.dataset.value;
   //If mine is clicked.
   if (val === -1) {
      openSingleBlock(this);
   }

   //Empty block
   else if (val === 0) {
      openBlock(this);
      openSingleBlock(this);
   }

   //For blocks touching mines.
   else {
      openSingleBlock(this);
   }
}

//A function which open the blocks recursively
function openBlock(td) {
   const [x, y] = td.id.split(",").map(Number);

   //If the block is not empty then don't proceed further.
   if (+td.dataset.value !== 0) return false;
   let touchingBlocks = touchingBlockArr.map(([dx, dy]) => [x + dx, dy + y]);
   openSingleBlock(td);
   touchingBlocks.forEach(([x, y]) => {
      //To checks if blocks are not out of range
      if (blocks[x] === undefined) return false;
      if (blocks[x][y] === undefined) return false;

      let val = +blocks[x][y].dataset.value;
      let td = blocks[x][y];
      //Not a mine
      if (val !== -1) {
         //Not touching mine and not opened and not flagged.
         if (
            val === 0 &&
            !td.classList.contains("opened")
         ) {
            openBlock(td);
         }

         //Touching a mine
         else {
            openSingleBlock(td);
         }
      }
   });
}


newGame(50, 50);
```

```css
body {
   font-family: cursive;
}

.block {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: lightgray;
   filter: brightness(0.8);
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 0.25rem;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px c10px black;
   background-size: contain;
}
.block:hover {
   filter: brightness(1);
}

.opened {
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   filter: brightness(1);
}

#main {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.opened.mine {
   background-image: url(mine.jpg);
   background-size: contain;
}

.flagged {
   background-image: url(flag.png);
   background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<table id="main"></table>
```

If you have any tips to increase performance of code please add it to your answer.

Comment: _"Its much but you have to only concentrate on `openBlock` function which is called recursively."_ - So why would you add _all_ instead of only the relevant function (or at least only a [mcve])

Comment: If recursion is causing the problem, then the simplest answer would be to not use recursion. You could maintain a stack of `td` that need to be checked and have an outer loop that pops items from the stack and checks them until the stack is empty.

Comment: @JLRishe I am sure how to do that. I have removed some of the unnecessary code from the snippet. If will help it will be very nice

Comment: You could use `setTimeout`s on `openBlock`s. It might not be the best solution but at least you get the nice little "animation" (delay) when opening the blocks

Comment: @ThumChoonTat That's a good idea. And game looks more better. But when the board is large its opening very slow.

Comment: @MaheerAli What value are you using for the timeout value? Even a value of `0` should work since that will reset the stack.

Comment: @JLRishe I am using `0`. The code is not giving error now. But the opening is not smooth. Its irregular and slow.

Comment: @JLRishe For upto 20x20 its looks even better than previous but as I increase number it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, the simplest way to solve an overflowing stack due to recursion is to not use recursion.

In this case you can use the following algorithm:

When user clicks an empty block (here, "empty block" means a block with no mine and no adjacent mines):

1. Push the block to an empty stack
2. While the stack is non-empty:

   1. Pop the top item from the stack
   2. If the item is not yet open:

      1. Mark the item as open
      2. Check the item's neighbors - push any empty, non-opened neighbors to the stack and mark any non-mine neighbors that have adjacent mines as open

Here is the central portion of that algorithm:

```
function openBlocks(startingBlock) {
    let blocksToOpen = [startingBlock];

    while (blocksToOpen.length) {
        let nextBlock = blocksToOpen.pop();

        if (!nextBlock.classList.contains("opened")) {
            // openBlock returns an array of empty neighbors that are not
            // yet open
            let additionalBlocksToOpen = openBlock(nextBlock);

            if (additionalBlocksToOpen.length) {
                blocksToOpen = [...blocksToOpen, ...additionalBlocksToOpen];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See below for the full solution.

FYI, I think this would run considerably faster if you used plain objects to represent the game data and only touch the DOM when you need to change part of it (reveal a block, etc.). The DOM is notoriously slow for various reasons.

```js
// -1 => mine
// 0 => a block without touching any mine
// 1 => block touching 1 mine
// etc

//Helper Methods
//Short for querySelector and querySelectorAll
const qs = str => document.querySelector(str);
const qsa = str => document.querySelectorAll(str);

//To create an element
const ce = ({ tag, style, ...rest }) => {
   const element = document.createElement(tag);
   if (rest) {
      for (let k in rest) {
         element[k] = rest[k];
      }
   }
   return element;
};

const main = qs("#main");
//Main variables
let len, wid, mines, blocks;
let isPlaying = true;

//Helping Data
let touchingBlockArr = [
   [1, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [1, 1],
   [1, -1]
];
touchingBlockArr = touchingBlockArr.concat(
   touchingBlockArr.map(x => x.map(a => -a))
);

//Object to assign colors for different numbers.
const colorObj = {
   "-1": "red",
   0: "gray",
   1: "blue",
   2: "orange",
   3: "green",
   4: "purple",
   5: "maroon"
};

//Function to create new game.
function newGame(l, w, m = 10) {
   len = l;
   wid = w;
   mines = m;
   main.innerHTML = "";
   game = [];
   blocks = [];
   createBoard();
}

//Create board
function createBoard() {
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      let tr = ce({ tag: "tr" });
      blocks.push([]);
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
         let td = ce({
            className: "block",
            tag: "td",
            onclick: onBlockClick,
            id: `${i},${j}`
         });
         tr.appendChild(td);
         td.id = `${i},${j}`;
         blocks[blocks.length - 1].push(td);
      }
      main.appendChild(tr);
   }
   addMines();
   setValues();
}

//Adding Mines
function addMines() {
   let addedMines = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < mines; i++) {
      let str, randX, randY;
      //To avoid repition of mines on same block.
      do {
         randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * wid);
         randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
         str = `${randX},${randY}`;
      } while (addedMines.includes(str));
      addedMines.push(str);

      blocks[randX][randY].classList.add("mine");
      blocks[randX][randY].setAttribute("data-value", -1);
   }
}

//Set Numbers for each block
function setValues() {
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
         let val;
         let tile = +blocks[i][j].dataset.value;
         if (tile !== -1) {
            val = touchingBlockArr.filter(([y, x]) => {
               if (blocks[i + y] && blocks[i + y][j + x]) {
                  return +blocks[i + y][j + x].dataset.value === -1;
               }
            }).length;
         }
         val = val === undefined ? -1 : val;
         blocks[i][j].setAttribute("data-value", val);
         blocks[i][j].style.color = colorObj[val];
      }
   }
}


function openSingleBlock(td) {
   let val = +td.dataset.value;
   if (val === -1) {
   } else {
      td.innerHTML = val || "";
   }
   td.classList.add("opened");
}

function openBlocks(startingBlock) {
    let blocksToOpen = [startingBlock];
    
    while (blocksToOpen.length) {
        let nextBlock = blocksToOpen.pop();

        if (!nextBlock.classList.contains("opened")) {
            // openBlock returns an array of empty neighbors that are not
            // yet open
            let additionalBlocksToOpen = openBlock(nextBlock);

            if (additionalBlocksToOpen.length) {
                blocksToOpen = [...blocksToOpen, ...additionalBlocksToOpen];
            }
        }
    }
}

//When a left mouse button is clicked
function onBlockClick() {
   if (this.classList.contains("flagged")) return false;
   let val = +this.dataset.value;
   //If mine is clicked.
   if (val === -1) {
      openSingleBlock(this);
   }

   //Empty block
   else if (val === 0) {
      openBlocks(this);
   }

   //For blocks touching mines.
   else {
      openSingleBlock(this);
   }
}

function alreadyOpened(td) {
    return td.classList.contains('opened');
} 

//A function which open the blocks recursively
function openBlock(td) {
   let blocksToOpen = [];       

   const [x, y] = td.id.split(",").map(Number);

   //If the block is not empty then don't proceed further.
   if (+td.dataset.value !== 0) return false;
   let touchingBlocks = touchingBlockArr.map(([dx, dy]) => [x + dx, dy + y]);
   openSingleBlock(td);
   touchingBlocks.forEach(([x, y]) => {
      //To checks if blocks are not out of range
      if (blocks[x] === undefined) return false;
      if (blocks[x][y] === undefined) return false;

      let val = +blocks[x][y].dataset.value;
      let td = blocks[x][y];
      //Not a mine
      if (val !== -1) {
         //Not touching mine and not opened and not flagged.
         if (
            val === 0 &&
            !alreadyOpened(td)
         ) {
            blocksToOpen.push(td);
         }

         //Touching a mine
         else {
            openSingleBlock(td);
         }
      }
   });
   
   return blocksToOpen;
}


newGame(50, 50, 20);
```

```css
body {
   font-family: cursive;
}

.block {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: lightgray;
   filter: brightness(0.8);
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 0.25rem;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px c10px black;
   background-size: contain;
}
.block:hover {
   filter: brightness(1);
}

.opened {
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   filter: brightness(1);
}

#main {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.opened.mine {
   background-image: url(mine.jpg);
   background-size: contain;
}

.flagged {
   background-image: url(flag.png);
   background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<table id="main"></table>
```